# Inno Setup:Automatic rollback process

Tags: inno-setup

As part of installation, sometimes i see few erors during a file replacement etc, so then inno setup gives a message like "abort/retry/ignore" if the user chooses abort inno setup rollbacks the installation.
So i want to know 2 things here
1)I wanted to know from my installer, whether a roll back is invoked or not? can inno setup give any acknowledgeent for automatic rollback happend or not?
2)what are the steps of rollback, what all does it do in that? a detailed explanation would be very helpful...

Comment: From a quick view in the source... 1) It could, if something like that were implemented. Currently, you can only *guess* that rollback was performed if you check [`the exit code`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes), but this can be done only when the setup process terminates. 2) In short, all what is performed in [`TUninstallLog.PerformUninstall`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Undo.pas#L590). It is commented, so from that you may extract the answer. In all cases would be nice to have an extra `TSetupStep`, something like `ssRollback`.

Comment: @TLama, Thanks for quick answer, i will use installer exit codes.

Comment: You're welcome! But it's merely a comment, because I don't think there's a way different from checking the exit code. But maybe I'm wrong...